# sql duplicate removal from report

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have access to a large datawarehouse that I can't control (*), just write queries to.

One of the tables that shouldn't contain duplicates does and I need to pick out the line relating to the most recent active field. For example:

```
Name | Date    | Status   | Type
Jon  | 01/2/15 | Active   | Ext
Jon  | 30/1/15 | Inactive | Res
Sam  | <null>  | Active   | Res
Guy  | 01/2/15 | Active   | Res
Guy  | 02/2/15 | Active   | Sem
Guy  | 03/2/15 | Inactive | Key
```

I need to return:

```
Name | Date    | Status   | Type
Jon  | 01/2/15 | Active   | Ext
Sam  | <null>  | Active   | Res
Guy  | 02/2/15 | Active   | Sem
```

I have had a search around, but can't really work out a way to get what I need!

I've got as far as:

```
Select Name.acc, Date.acc, Status.acc, Type.acc
From DimAccounts as Acc
Where        (ACC.AccountStatus = 'Current')
```

Then it gets a bit messy!

I'm using visual studio in case that makes any difference

- I tell them about problems and *they* fix them in their own sweet time

Comment: See edits and comments I made to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a subquery in my book. Using a subquery with a row_number() ordered by date and partitioned by group will return the most recent record per group.

```
Select MainAcc.Name, MainAcc.Date, MainAcc.Status, MainAcc.Type, 
       as subAcc where MainAcc.Id = subAcc.Id

From DimAccounts as MainAcc inner join
      (select id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                            ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
      from DimAccounts) as subAcc on subAcc.Id = MainAcc.Id and subAcc.rn = 1
```

Here I'm assuming that there are some unique Ids that you can make use of.

EDIT: I redid this query because of issues with the original. I think that this version is a better one. However, the original one (which used a subquery with top 1) may be useful for you depending on the restrictions/business requirements in your database.

Comment: Ah ha! Select Top, that's what I need. I think I can work it out from that. And yes there are indeed many other columns that I didn't bother mentioning including a Unique ID. And apparently I can't up a response till I have 15 rep... thanks anyway!

Comment: @Khornight , I edited my answer significantly to improve it. The first answer, going down the path of top 1, may work well for you, depending on the tables you are working with. But I think that this new answer is a better one and will work more smoothly for you.

Comment: Also, you can accept my answer instead of upvoting if you feel it is correct.

Comment: hmmm, this brings up more questions! From my understanding of top, I'm creating something very similar to your partition, ie an inner join where one table is the unique id returned by top (albeit a combination of non unique key and the date field) and the other is the line from the table I want! What is the difference between that and the partition method in your second example?

Comment: Well, the main difference is that top 1 will only return the top row from the result set, which in my original meant that among all the IDs, only one would be returned, instead of getting one result for each ID. That original query really only works if you use the top 1 subquery as a correlated subquery - that is a special type of subquery that is worth researching a bit if you are just starting out in SQL, but basically means in this case that the subquery would run once for every ID in the main query. Correlated subqueries can also be notoriously slow. This new query would likely be better.

Comment: Ah, I have discovered the same about top... now reading everything around partitions! (I simplified my real query so now I have to translate it all so it still works! :-)

Comment: I'd recommend specifically looking into the RowNumber() function - any description of it will include information on how the partition is used in it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

THis is the unsimplified answer I used, which I got from the other question I started ([SQL: Why is distinct and max not removing duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230359/sql-why-is-distinct-and-max-not-removing-duplicates/)):

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             max(accountID) over (partition by propertyid) as max_tsd
      from dimaccount a
      where accountstatus = 'Current'
     ) a
where accountID = max_tsd;
```

Ended up using the unique ID as it incrementally increases. Visual studio says it doesn't support over, but it seems to work fine!?